# Laravel Extend Vendor Class

Tags: php, laravel, translation

I tried extending an Illuminate Class Translator

I created a class and extended to translator
then I added this line to my RepositoryServiceProvider

```
$this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Translation\Translator::class, \App\Repositories\Translation\TranslationTranslator::class);
```

But its not working

what am I doing wrong?

the class as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Translation;

use Countable;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;
use Illuminate\Support\NamespacedItemResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;


class TranslationTranslator extends \Illuminate\Translation\Translator
{
    /**
     * Parse a key into namespace, group, and item.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return array
     */
    public function parseKey($key)
    {
        \Log::info('got in');
        die;
        $segments = parent::parseKey($key);

        if (is_null($segments[0])) {
            $segments[0] = @explode('.', $segments[2])[0];
        }
        if ($segments[1] == 'translatable') {
            $segments[1] = @explode('.', $segments[2])[0] . '_' . @explode('.', $segments[2])[1];
        }
        return $segments;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently the Translator class has a constructor

```
 public function __construct(LoaderInterface $loader, $locale)
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }
```

so my binding has to pass by the interface.. which cannot be instantiated

```
 public function boot()
{
    $app = $this->app;
    $this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Translation\Translator::class, function() use ($app){
        return $app->make(\App\Repositories\Translation\TranslationTranslator::class);
    });        
}
```

and getting this error

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException with message
>   'Target [Illuminate\Translation\LoaderInterface] is not instantiable
>   while building [App\Repositories\Translation\TranslationTranslator].'

Comment: could you provide me package which you want to override class. Then I can check and help to solve your problem.

Comment: Illuminate\Translation\Translator;

public function parseKey()

Comment: share composer package url or name so that I can check. Not class namespace :)

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.html

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use closure to resolve the classes

```
$this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Translation\Translator::class, function(){

    return new \App\Repositories\Translation\TranslationTranslator;
});
```

Secondly translator is binded with laravel in using `translator` alias.

You can also override it.

```
$this->app->bind('translator', function(){
        return new \App\Repositories\Translation\TranslationTranslator; 
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
$app = $this->app;
$loader = $app['translation.loader'];
$locale = $app['config']['app.locale'];

$this->app->bind('translator', function() use ($loader, $locale){
    return new \App\Repositories\Translation\TranslationTranslator($loader, $locale);
});
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
$this->app->instance(\Illuminate\Translation\Translator::class, \App\Repositories\Translation\TranslationTranslator::class);
```

That should then change the instance of the interface.

**UPDATE**

if you are just trying to add a new method, the Translator class is Macroable. So you can do the following

```
Translator::macro('parseKey', function ($key) {
    \Log::info('got in');
    die;
    $segments = parent::parseKey($key);

    if (is_null($segments[0])) {
        $segments[0] = @explode('.', $segments[2])[0];
    }
    if ($segments[1] == 'translatable') {
        $segments[1] = @explode('.', $segments[2])[0] . '_' . @explode('.', $segments[2])[1];
    }
    return $segments;
});
```

You would then be able to call your method as you normally would. For example:

```
app(Translator::class)->parseKey($key);
```

Comment: this didnt work.. do I need to clear cache or something ?

Comment: Is your service provider registered in your `app.php` file and have you put this call in the `boot` method?

Answer (score 0):

Check below example

```
namespace App\Repositories\Translation;

use Illuminate\Translation\Translator;
class TranslationTranslator extends Translator
{

    public function get()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

No need to anything. you only need to add new functions or override base class functions. Then you can use this class as simple other classes.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly needs to be done? How should Laravel know about that overriden class?

Comment: @NicoHaase laravel autoload all the classes inside `app` directory. So you have no need to load this file.. and regarding override. we extend `Vendor` package class. by using this we can override or add new functions in our new file.

Comment: I am trying to replace a method with a method of my own from the translator class called parseKey()

Comment: @GarinePondikian check `Vendor` class dependencies. and also add in this file.

Comment: @GarinePondikian could you share `TranslationTranslator` class code, I think you are doing something wrong.. because `parseKey()` function need one parameter.

Comment: @LuckySaini i am passing the $key variable

Comment: change your `parseKey()` function with this
`public function parseKey($key) { 
   \Log::info('got in'); die; 
  } `
you have to use this `\Log::info()` instead of `\log::info()`. I think this is the issue.

Comment: @GarinePondikian one more thing, `namespace` should be at the top of the file above the `use` statement, for best practice,

Comment: @LuckySaini I think another binding is overriding mine on runtime.. I did all above and nothing worked

Comment: @LuckySaini I know about the concept of an autoloader, but why should Laravel pick up any class to do something? I don't think that extending alone is the problem here